# What is happening to the okra plants

Tags: vegetables, okra

Recently i have been growing okra plants from seeds and i find that out of all the shoots three of them wilted. Completely puzzled on what has been happening to the plants? I have attached a photograph of it. The leaves in the recent shoots have yellow spots on the leaves.

[image: Recent Okra shoot]

Comment: I don't see wilting in your picture.  The yellow spots could easily be a fly who put her eggs inside the leaf itself.  Transitory.  I'd cut them off later, not now.  I think that glaucous or whitish covering is normal for ocra leaves.  It is a bit early for powdery mildew.  Are these in your out door garden or are these plants in a greenhouse?  They seem to be planted in pots, yes?  Please send what pnuts has asked for sure and another picture or two showing the entire plant/pot kitnkaboodle?  Are you in the southern states?  Grins!  Where do you live?

Comment: @stormyThank you for the inputs. Yes, Its on my terrace and i have planted inside a grow bag with cocopeat as the potting mix. I live in India.

Comment: @pnuts Occasionally i have been using diluted bokashi tea, the panchagavya mix and vermicompost as fertilizer. Ample sunlight is available throughout the day.

Answer (score 1):

were you able to solve the problem at that time?

It seems to me that the problem must come from some virus. It is quite common for the whitefly to transmit a virus that brings problems similar to those in the photo.

It can also be a problem of lack of nutrients. There is a lot of information about fertilization on the Internet, you can consult this article on [how to fertilize okras](https://fertilizerfor.com/okra/) if you need to delve into the subject.

Comment: Good answer; if could include additional specific details and suggestions, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], especially [Ask] and [Answer], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!